# ovr_CreateSwapTextureSetGL fails [OpenGL + Oculus 0.8.0 / DK2]

Tags: opengl, oculus

As you probably know, the DK2 supports a new mode called Direct Mode that reduces latency and hence improves the VR experience. When I run the DK2 samples that come with the currently latest 0.8.0(beta) SDK, the DiredctX11 version of the *OculusTinyRoom* runs fine.

My problem: The OpenGL (using 3.3 profile) version uses a function called *ovrHmd_CreateSwapTextureSetGL()* that returns a textureset with zero textures (but calls *glGenBuffer* as fallback), and the return value is -1006 (ovrServiceError).

I've seen many reports on the problematic OpenGL support on the Oculus Developer Forum. For earlier versions of the SDK the OpenGL support was neglected from 0.2.4+ and seem to have been resolved from versions 0.5 and up (all in Client Rendering Mode). Nothing said about the newer Direct Mode, except that for some people it failed to work at all if they had their second screen attached, even in DirectX11. This is not the case for me.

I've also seen people suggest to *[uninstall](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=10968&start=280)* the 3D Vision drivers from NVidia, because they may conflict with the Oculus Rift drivers. They report dramatic framerate improvements, although I get a 10% improvement myself. Apparently NVidia's GameWorks VR bites driver performance just by installing it. Unfortunately, uninstalling them does not fix the problem.

The latest driver (361.34) update suggests improved Oculus and OpenGL support in , GameWorks VR OpenGL, as well as Direct Mode support (even for SLI setups, which seems to have pretty [impressive results](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/3gwnsm/nvidia_gameworks_vr_sli_test/)). But that's an NVidia-only solution. AMD has [LiquidVR](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/380q80/gameworks_vs_liquidvr/) as an alternative. But I'd still like to use the Oculus SDK stack.

I am using both a Geforce 480 and Titan X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the second screen issue that some seem to have had.  Since it worked for me in DX11, I figured my problem would not be similar.

During my research I found a few interesting [forum post](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2f97fh/some_tips_when_using_your_oculus_rift_dk2/) on reddit suggesting that part of the problem might stem from using multiple monitors. It turns out it seems to have been fixed for DX11 but not for OpenGL in the meantime.

So I can confirm that turning off any secondary screens connected to secondary cards fixes the problem. For OpenGL, you have to connect ALL your output devices to the SAME card.

I did some more testing:

What worked:

- Primary screen AND oculus both connected to the TitanX (The 480 isn't connected).
- Connecting both screens and the Oculus to the Titan worked(!)

What did not work:

- Connecting the primary to the Titan and the Oculus to the 480 does not work.
- Connecting the primary to the 480 and the Oculus to the Titan also does not work.

So it seems to be a driver issue with the graphics device enumeration.

Note: This was AFTER I removed the NVidia 3D Vision drivers and updated to build 361.43, so it might also still have been related to having them installed. If someone can confirm this, would be nice to know.